# System of equations - What's wrong with my solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

The system of equations below can be solved by substitution or elimination. I understand the official solution to this problem, which I will provide below. I'd like to understand why my initial solution failed, thank you for your assistance.

#### Equations:

Equation One: $$x + y = 3000$$
Equation Two: $$0.1x + 0.08y = 256$$

---

#### Correct Solution (substitution method):

$$y = -x + 3000$$
$$0.1x + 0.08(-x + 3000) = 256$$
$$x = 800$$
$$y = 2,200$$

---

#### My (incorrect) solution:

$$0.08y = 256 - 0.1x$$
$$y = \frac{256 - 0.1x}{0.08}$$
$$x + \frac{256 - 0.1x}{0.08} = 3000$$
$$x + 256 - 0.1x = 3000 \times 0.08$$
$$0.9x = -16$$
$$x = -17.78$$

So where did I go wrong?

Comment: You might find this helpful for formatting your question http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $X + 256-.1X = 3000(.08)   $  you multiplied it wrong  this is right one $.8X + 256-.1X = 3000(.08)   $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fourth step, you didn't multiply $X$ by $0.08$ on the left side.